# Wrong project is being run in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote some java code in Eclipse. When I run it, I see the output of another project (that I wrote before) in the console. How can I see the output of my new code?

Comment: I don't understand your question yet, you should describe it clearly.

Comment: How are you running your new code? If you just hit run on the tool bar it reruns the last thing you ran. Right click the new code and click "run as"

Comment: click on the `small arrow` besides `run` button in toolbar and select your the project you want to run.

Comment: @khadije, try close all of other projects.

Comment: Do Nhu Vy: it's pretty obvious. Person creates a project called "Project1". Compiles it. It runs. They then want to do a second project called "Project2". They do a hello world for "Project2" then they compile it. Eclipse runs off and compiles "Project1". User spends hours hunting through menus trying to work out why. Comes to stack overflow to ask, and gets you asking what they mean to add to their frustration. It's obvious what they mean!

Comment: For anyone coming across this question having the same problem, check your project main() class has  `main(String[] args)`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to guess your problem: When you press the `Run as` button (White arrow in green circle), Eclipse doesn't run the program you're editing. Instead, it runs again the last program you executed. That's the reason why you see the output of another project: You're telling Eclipse to repeat its execution.

So, to run your new app, right click over the code and select Run as/Java application.

Comment: thanks.... i select the project in the project explorer and then select Run as/Java application.

Comment: @khadij, don't select the project. Select the class you want to execute.

Comment: But if you are working on two projects at the same time. How do you switch between one and the other? How do you know which project is open? That's the real question here.

Comment: Both projects are open, and classes from both projects can be run.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your project in the project explorer. And then this menu will pop up:
[image]

Click Run As > Java Application